# How do I get SalesForce Table Names from SalesForce data

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud

How to get all table names in salesforce data using query. for example, In postgreSQL If i give  SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables , it will give all table names from information_schema. Same way how can i get all table names from salesforce data?.

Comment: Hi, instead of query you should use apex for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this with a query, but you can use the [describeGlobal](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_describeglobal.htm?CSHID=sforce_api_calls_describeglobal.htm) call (via SOAP or REST), or the [Schema](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/Chunk1531839598.htm#apex_methods_system_schema) object in apex to obtain schema information include table & field names, types, etc.